# Dell laptop 5010 fans don't throttle

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, graphics-card, fan, dell-inspiron

My dell Inspiron n5010 fans work without throttling.

- I had an 8 beep error which I searched the Google and says it is the video card.
- I took it for a repair and was told that the problem wasn't the video card - it was some chip on the board which was replaced.
- The 8 beep problem is solved and I can work with my system but now the problem is that the laptop fans work without throttling.
- I checked on Windows 10 and Ubuntu, both of them have the same issue.
- There are no process intensive application running (like games, autocad, etc).
- The CPU and RAM are normal.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: i fear about my fans, doesn't it burn

Comment: what was the CPU utilization percentage?

Comment: it is less than 25 percent

Comment: the laptop is cool

Comment: i also get same issue when the cpu percentage is 14